# Java Exception in thread java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I have a java app source code, and it gets an error same as app that I write code here.
both of them get this:
" Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException "
if I fix this, then I can fix the problem in my primary java app.

When I run this java app, it run once, and when back to do-while loop, it gets error.
" Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException "

Code:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    int c=-1;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
        System.out.println("1- Sum");
        System.out.println("2- Sub");
        System.out.print("Enter your selection : > ");
        c=input.nextInt();
        res(c);
    }while(c!=0);
    input.close();
}

public static void res(int c) {
    switch (c) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("++++++++++");
        sum();
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("----------");
        sub();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
public static void sum() {
    float a,b,c;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter two number :");
    System.out.print("first number : ");
    a=in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("second number : ");
    b=in.nextInt();
    c=a+b;
    System.out.println(a+" + "+b+" = "+c+"   END.");
    in.close();
}
public static void sub() {
    float a,b,c;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter two number :");
    System.out.print("first number : ");
    a=in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("second number : ");
    b=in.nextInt();
    c=a-b;
    System.out.println(a+" - "+b+" = "+c+"   END.");
    in.close();
}
```

Does anyone can help me to fix this?

Comment: `" Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException "` Is that all you get?  no stack trace? no line numbers?

Comment: It wont solve your problem, but in both your sub and sum methods, you are reading in floats using the in.nextInt();  This is setting yourself up for a very easily thrown InputMismatchException.

EDIT: I just copied your code and ran it without issues

Comment: Both the below answers are correct.  I can reproduce the problem which is explained by Jim.  Pignic then gives you the solution.  You may also want to add is some validation that a number is entered.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the `Scanner` at the end of `sum()` and `sub()`, which you should not be doing.  Remove those two statements and the problem should be fixed.

What is happening is that the `Scanner#close()` method closes the underlying input stream as well, so the next time through the main loop `System.in` has been closed, causing the exception.

Comment: He has created new Scanners, it does not matter that he closes his new Scanner there

Comment: Read the API description in the Javadoc. Closing a `Scanner` closes the underlying stream.

Comment: @JimGarrison He posted that before you added the note that the underlying input stream also gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should open your Scanner once for all

- use it as a private static field,
- initialize it in the start of the main,
- close it at the end,
- call it normaly.

Good luck